# String comparison: InvariantCultureIgnoreCase vs OrdinalIgnoreCase?

Tags: c#, string

Which would be better code:

```
int index = fileName.LastIndexOf(".", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

or

```
int index = fileName.LastIndexOf(".", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: that would depend on what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: @MartinLiversage marking c# question as duplicate of vb.net question.. funny at least. Believe both should share .Net tag in this case

Comment: @Lanorkin: The distinction between the two enum values are the same in VB.NET and C# and none of the answers to both this question and the other are specific to either VB.NET or C#. The two questions are clearly duplicates and by associating them as I have done it becomes easier to find the relevant information about these enum values.

Comment: @MartinLiversage exactly that's why I use word "funny"

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate question because this question is asking about file name parsing and the other question seems to be asking about user input. File name parsing has different requirements. I wish the title started off with "String comparison of file names: ...", then this question would be clearer.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you really want to match only the dot, then `StringComparison.Ordinal` would be fastest, as there is no case-difference.

"Ordinal" doesn't use culture and/or casing rules that are not applicable anyway on a symbol like a `.`.

Answer (score 315):

Neither code is always better. They do different things, so they are good at different things.

`InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` uses comparison rules based on english, but without any regional variations. This is good for a neutral comparison that still takes into account some linguistic aspects.

`OrdinalIgnoreCase` compares the character codes without cultural aspects. This is good for exact comparisons, like login names, but not for sorting strings with unusual characters like `é` or `ö`. This is also faster because there are no extra rules to apply before comparing.

Comment: how does `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase ` behave when he meet `ä` ? as oppose to  `OrdinalIgnoreCase ` ...?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: The invariant culture is based on english, so it would treat `ä`, `à`, `å`, et.c. as `a`, i.e. remove diacritics. Using an ordinal culture would place the characters with diacritics after all the regular letters, i.e. sorted strictly on character code.

Comment: you mean that they all will be uppercase A (InvariantCultureIgnoreCase ) right ?

Comment: but also OrdinalIgnoreCase compares the character codes without cultural aspects......so ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yes, the case will be ignored when they are compared. `OrdinalIgnoreCase` makes a case conversion, but then it compares on the character code, so `à` and `À` are equal, but `A` and `À` are different.

Comment: according to your first comment to me : why this code `string s1 = "hello";string s2 = "héllo";
     s1.Equals(s2, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)` return False ? you said that a and à is treated the same...

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yes, you are right, the characters are not treated as strictly equal, but when you sort strings the `é` will be right after `e`, not somewhere after `z`.

Comment: so it is for sorting and not for equalizing ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yes, for that character it works that way, other characters may actually be evaluated as equal, or a character may be equal to two other characters. The strings `"lasst"` and `"laßt"` are actually equal.

Comment: This is one explanation that really helped me understand..

Comment: @Guffa Strictly speaking, it is a bad idea to do case insensitive comparison for passwords. Password comparison should use `Ordinal`, not `OrdinalIgnoreCase`

Comment: @SveinFidjestøl: Good point. I used a different example in the answer.

Comment: hi thank you for your answer Mr @Guffa - could you elaborate more on what you mean by:  "takes into account some linguistic aspects"?

Comment: Beware of OrdinalIgnoreCase when you compare human-readable strings at all, the letters I and i are different letters in Turkish locale!

Comment: For anyone else that is curious, the term to search for to get a list of equivalent characters is "unicode case folding".

Answer (score 66):

FXCop typically prefers `OrdinalIgnoreCase`.  But your requirements may vary.

For English there is very little difference. It is when you wander into languages that have different written language constructs that this becomes an issue. I am not experienced enough to give you more than that.

OrdinalIgnoreCase

> The StringComparer returned by the 
>   OrdinalIgnoreCase property treats 
>   the characters in the strings to
>   compare as if they were converted
>   to uppercase using the conventions
>   of the invariant culture, and then
>   performs a simple byte comparison
>   that is independent of language.
>   This is most appropriate when
>   comparing strings that are generated
>   programmatically or when comparing
>   case-insensitive resources such as
>   paths and filenames.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase.aspx

InvariantCultureIgnoreCase

> The StringComparer returned by the
>   InvariantCultureIgnoreCase property
>   compares strings in a linguistically
>   relevant manner that ignores case, but
>   it is not suitable for display in any
>   particular culture. Its major
>   application is to order strings in a
>   way that will be identical across
>   cultures.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.invariantcultureignorecase.aspx
>
> The invariant culture is the
>   CultureInfo object returned by the
>   InvariantCulture property.
>
> The InvariantCultureIgnoreCase
>   property actually returns an instance
>   of an anonymous class derived from the
>   StringComparer class.

Answer (score 18):

You seem to be doing file name comparisons, so I would just add that `OrdinalIgnoreCase` is *closest* to what NTFS does (it's not exactly the same, but it's closer than `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`)

Comment: Have you got a reference for what NTFS does?