# How Do I get list of audio/video and capture devices in C#?

Tags: c#, audio, video, webcam, capture

I've spent the last two weeks searching everywhere trying to get even so much as a hint on how to do this. This is my first time asking, and trust me when I say that I do not like to ask for help.

But I am at the end of my rope, all I can find is how to list available audio and video devices using someone else's Framework in C#. All I want to do is list the available audio and video devices connected to ones computer from within C# without any additional 3rd party Frameworks.

If any of you could help with this, I would greatly appreciate it. Like I said, I'm at the end of my rope trying to figure out how to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Googling for ["C# get video capture devices"](http://www.google.com/search?q=c#%20get%20video%20capture%20devices).  I ended up at these two CodeProject articles:

- [DirectShow.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2615/DirectShow-NET)
- [DirectX.Capture Class Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3566/DirectX-Capture-Class-Library)

You'll see that there is a lot of COM interop involved. And from the sound of it, I'm not sure you're ready to jump right into that, at it can be a lot of tedious work. I would consider using what is there, and not re-inventing the wheel. After all, they are both in the [public domain](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/publicdomain/).

Additionally, there is this post on StackOverflow which has some interesting links:

- [Get default audio/video device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438628/get-default-audio-video-device)

Answer (score 2):

Try `aForge.net`  http://www.aforgenet.com/  it is fairly simple doing exactly that, or you can use their ready made dialog if it is enough for you.

Answer (score -2):

```
        /// <summary>
        /// The DirectSoundEnumerate function enumerates the DirectSound Odrivers installed in the system.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="lpDSEnumCallback">callback function</param>
        /// <param name="lpContext">User context</param>
        [DllImport("dsound.dll", EntryPoint = "DirectSoundEnumerateA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        static extern void DirectSoundEnumerate(DevicesEnumCallback lpDSEnumCallback, IntPtr lpContext);


        /// <summary>
        /// The DirectSoundEnumerate function enumerates the DirectSound Input drivers installed in the system.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="lpDSEnumCallback">callback function</param>
        /// <param name="lpContext">User context</param>
        [DllImport("dsound.dll", EntryPoint = "DirectSoundCaptureEnumerateA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        static extern void DirectSoundCaptureEnumerate(DevicesEnumCallback lpDSEnumCallback, IntPtr lpContext);
```

Comment: @jam: there's little to explain here. These are P/Invoke declarations for obsolete audio only API. It does not really answers original question.