# Case-Insensitive String Comparison not working in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Based on the answer to this question:

[How can I do a case insensitive string comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121957/c-sharp-case-insensitive-string-compare)

I'm trying to do a case-insensitive comparison without using Compare or ToLower:

```
var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(s => String.Equals(s.Username, username, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

However I get an error:

> Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Boolean
>   Equals(System.String, System.String, System.StringComparison)'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you verified that username and s.Username are of type string.

Comment: Pretty sure L2S doesn't support that particular method.  If this was actual executable C# code and not something translated by a query provider it would be just fine.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid using string.Compare?

Comment: @tsells Because Equals() more accurately represents the condition.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The string comparison with `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` works in memory or with `IEnumerable<T>`. You are trying to use it with `IQueryable<T>`, but the provider of your queryable does not understand it.

In Linq-to-Sql you should be able to use `SqlMethods.Like(s.UserName, userName)`, like this:

```
var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(s => SqlMethods.Like(s.UserName, userName));
```

[SqlMethods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods(v=vs.110).aspx) is in the System.Data.Linq.SqlClient namespace.

The `Like` method is case-insensitive, so you should get the expected result.

> **EDIT :** I tried and get "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method `Boolean Like(System.String, System.String)` method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

This appears to be a known issue with EF ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1033007/335858)).

> This works for me:
>
> ```
> db.Users.FirstOrDefault(
>      s => s.Username.Equals(username, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
> );
> ```

It appears that although EF has hard time translating the static `Equals` to SQL, it has no problem translating the instance `Equals`. This is a very good find - it makes for an easy to read, performant solution.

You could also use a simpler method with `ToUpperCase` or `ToLowerCase`, but that may prevent query optimizers from using indexes:

```
// Warning: this may not perform well.
var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(s => s.UserName.ToUpperCase() == userName.ToUpperCase());
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I tried and get "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Like(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression." - thoughts?

Comment: This works for me: db.Users.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Username.Equals(username, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));  I don't know what to do in terms of selecting an answer - feel free to make note of this and I can check yours off?

Comment: Would you say there's anything wrong with the solution I posted in the comment?  I was looking for a simple, performant solution that follows best practices.

Comment: @SB2055 Your solution is the best one: it's a little strange that EF has problems translating the static `Equals`, but takes the instance `Equals` well, but since the two functions are processed separately, it makes sense that one would work while the other would fail.