# Can I make C# Intellisense in VS 2013 use "String" instead of "string"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

I am old-fashioned, and prefer "String" (class) to "string" (basic type) in C#.  In Visual Studio, Intellisense always substitutes "string" for "String" so that I get things like:

```
static Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Tuple<String, String>>> s_edits = new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Tuple<string,string>>>
                                                                                   __________________________________________________________
```

where the underlined section was added by Intellisense.  Is there any way I can persuade VS to use "String"?

As you can imagine, trying to Google for "String" vs "string" isn't working :-(.

Comment: Perhaps this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187486/why-is-string-considered-a-simplified-version-of-string

Comment: I don't get the old-fashioned thing either. Generally, its preferred to use `string` when referring to the object, such as `string s="test";`. When accessing methods from the object, then it should be `String`, such as `String.Format("{0}", "test");`

Comment: You'll have to treat the person that is going to maintain your code some day as a homicidal maniac that knows where you live.  This will definitely set him off.

Comment: As a kinda-sorta rule (since I'm not using many structs), dark blue type means a value type and light blue is a reference type.  It's not hard and fast, obviously, but that's how my mind is parsing things.  'string' violates that assumption, causing me to waste a few extra neurons when I have few enough to spare...

Comment: My grandfather always gets on my case about that. He's like a broken record. "When I was your age, we used the `String` class, not some fancy new-fangled `string` type."

Comment: Why would you need to worry about details like whether a type is a reference type or a value type, except in rare cases? Certainly this doesn't seem like useful semantic information to always have at the forefront of your mind when writing code. Now, if the IDE was smart enough to highlight types differently that implemented IDisposable, *that* would be worthwhile...

Comment: > Certainly this doesn't seem like useful semantic information to always have at the forefront of your mind when writing code.

Comment: "Certainly this doesn't seem like useful semantic information to always have at the forefront of your mind when writing code."  Seriously?  The difference between value and reference types is relevant with every assignment (or comparison)!  (Couldn't edit my previous typo'd comment even though it was only a minute!)

Answer (score 4):

You can actually supress the warning that visual studio shows in 2 ways.

To do that on the **project level**:

```
Solution Explorer > Right Click Project > Properties > Build.
```

Next to Supress Warning, write **IDE0001**

**To do it globally for All projects**, you can:

```
Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > uncheck :
```

> Prefer intrinsic predefined type keyword when declaring locals,
>   parameters and members

Comment: I saw that option and posted it in an answer that is now deleted, but in my testing it did not affect the autocompletion the OP is asking about. Keywords are used for autocompletion regardless of that setting.

Comment: @mikez VS doesn't automatically substitute string with String. I have never experienced this. If you write `stri` and pres TAB, you get string.

Comment: No it doesn't but that is not what the question is. The OP wants "String" to be used by default for autocompletion. Do what you've described in your answer, then type what the OP has in the question and use the autocompletion option in the editor when you reach `new`. It still uses the `string` keyword regardless of that setting.

Comment: As mike z pointed out, this is when I use auto-complete after the 'new' keyword, so Intellisense writes out the declaration with the 'string' type keyword.