# Why does Visual Studio dim the word 'String' in C# Text Editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, editor

When upgrading from VS2013 to VS2017, I imported my previous environment settings but I'm encountering this odd editor behavior where the word 'String' is constantly dimmed:

[image]

The keyword 'string' is properly colored when in lowercase.

To be clear, it's using the proper color, that is, the color I'd expect when typing a classname as opposed to a keyword. But for some reason, it's dimming it the same way it would dim an unneeded 'using' statement or unreachable code.

Presumably the fix is in Options > Text Editor > C# somewhere but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Hover over the text and click the lightbulb. Alternatively, put your cursor over the text `String` and press `ctrl+.` (ctrl and a period). It will explain why it greyed out the text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is "string" considered a simplified version of "String"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187486/why-is-string-considered-a-simplified-version-of-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it is better practice to use string (lowercase) than String (with a big S). [These are the C# types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/types-and-variables). You will see that "string" is the basic value type. "String" is an alias.The greying out is hinting at this.

If you hover over it, you will get a refactoring recommendation.

[image]

Comment: better practice because...? I don't disagree but OP might like to know

Comment: Ah, that would explain it. I have the "Hide Lightbulb Margin" extension installed so may have missed it in the margin but, you're right, when I hover over it, it appears just as you've described. Is there a way to hide this refactoring recommendation IDE0049?

Comment: @FestusMartingale See the answer which was linked in a comment on your original question

Comment: Hi Canton, I did run across that question before posting my own. The aforementioned "Prefer intrinsic predefined type keyword when declaring locals, parameters and members" doesn't show up in my VS 2017. There *is* a 'predefined type preferences' settings block but oddly, tweaking these settings has no effect on the dimming and further, there seems to be no way to turn off the check completely.

Comment: These are the C# types. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/types-and-variables String is an alias. It's really no biggie, they compile to the same. We follow the default IDE recommendations since they are generally good practice and provide a level of standardisation to our code.

Comment: Another way is to add a custom ruleset. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-create-a-custom-rule-set?view=vs-2017). Then you can enable/disable rules individually, change their level (info/warning/error), etc. This particular rule is good for consistency, so I recommend following it.

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft `string` is the compiler alias, `System.String` is the framework type.

Comment: Here is a good post on the nuances between System.String and string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string-in-c

Comment: Except that since IDE0049 was introduced, I see far fewer people use the framework types for calling methods on, and they use the compiler alias everywhere.