# Simple C# login with 3 attempts with id case sensivtive/insensitive

Tags: c#

i need c# code in which user can login with 3 attempts and user id should be case insensitive and password should be case sensitive  would you please any one help. The code is given below:

C# code:

```
<code>
    //Login Attempts counter
    int loginAttempts = 0;

    //Simple iteration upto three times
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter username");
        string username = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter password");
        string password = Console.ReadLine();

        if (username != "EDUAdmin" || password != "edu@123")
            loginAttempts++;
        else
            break;
    }

    //Display the result
    if (loginAttempts > 2)
        Console.WriteLine("Login failure");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Login successful");

    Console.ReadKey();
</code>
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? The only obvious thing you should change is the if statement, you should check if username AND password match not one or the other. Therefore change || to &&.

Comment: And you didn't try to look for `case insensitive string comparison in C#` on Google. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What's the problem with your code ? If it's case insesnsitive for username, You may convert the user input and the real username to lower case using .ToLower()

Comment: @Adriani6 i need the which can accept username as case insensitive and password should be case sensitive. if the inputs are wrong the it will  show the message invalid loginid and password plzz try again

Comment: @MujtabaHussainBhat Then do username.toLower() on username as well as change the username string to "eduadmin" and leave the password as it is, but still chagne to &&...

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with the login attempt, you're just asking for case sensitive/insensitive string comparison which could be easily founded using any search engine. Here's a related question with answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121957/how-can-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison

Comment: @Adriani6 can you please update the code that will more appricited

Comment: @ T.Aoukar actually that is first criteria and the case sensitive and case insensitive

Comment: @MujtabaHussainBhat Posted as an answer. Not going to edit your question as it will no longer become a relevant part of this post.

Comment: @Adriani6  actually i am new for c# thats why i asking for that can you please help me out

Comment: @MujtabaHussainBhat do you want us to school you?? please learn basics of programming urself

Comment: if ((string.Compare(username, "EDUAdmin", true) == 0) && (string.Compare(password, "edu@123", false) == 0))
             break;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see comments under Question for clarification.

```
//Login Attempts counter
int loginAttempts = 0;

//Simple iteration upto three times
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter username");
    string username = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter password");
    string password = Console.ReadLine();

    if (username.ToLower() != "eduadmin" || password != "edu@123")
        loginAttempts++;
    else
        break;
}

//Display the result
if (loginAttempts > 2)
    Console.WriteLine("Login failure");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Login successful");

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: @RomaDoskoch Oops, I didn't realise it, for some reason I thought it goes straight to login success. My bad, still too early for me. Apologies and fixed.