# Match characters of two strings

Tags: c#, string

Suppose,i have two strings.`NameIs` and `Nam`.Now i can check if one string is as same as the other using :

```
If (string1 == string2)
```

But it won't work here as the strings are not the same.But a portion of it is same.What i am trying to achieve is to check if my main string has any portion of the string given...I came across `String.StartWith` and `EndWith` methods but there,i need to specify what the string might start or end with but i cannot as the strings can be anything(that's why at the beginning,i said "Suppose").

So my first question is how to achieve this ? I don't want any step=to=step instruction but atleast a little bit of direction :)

However,if i get past that,there's still a drawback and it is the `Case-Sensitive` issue.I've come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121957/how-can-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison) but i can't seem to figure the required implementation of this in my case because i need to overcome the first issue first.

How should i achieve these ?

Comment: Use .Contains(), its a string function which returns true if main string "contains" the substring

Comment: Really? you ask this?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring) might actually be a better duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [String.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx)

```
if (stringValue.ToLower().Contains(anotherString.ToLower())) {  
    // Do Work // 
}
```

Just remember to check that strings aren't null when doing contains comparing, or you will get an ArgumentNullException..

Comment: There are better ways to do case intensive checks than using `ToLower` or `ToUpper`.  It works for most character sets, but some languages have letters that don't have 1-to-1 mappings from lower to upper case.

Answer (score 3):

For ordinal comparison you can use

```
str1.Contains(str2);
```

If you need your comparison to be case-insensitive you can do

```
str1.IndexOf(str2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
```

---

Note that you can hide the latter in an extension method, like

```
static bool ContainsIgnoreCase(this string @this, string other)
    => @this.IndexOf(other, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
```

Comment: The OP stated 2 problems.Your solution get's rid of the first one somewhat.However,there's no explanation in your answer.Please edit it accordingly :)

Comment: Now,u deserve an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is this:

```
a = a?.ToLowerInvariant();
b = b?.ToLowerInvariant();

if(a==null || b==null || a.Contains(b) || b.Contains(a))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Why *null* propogates into *true*? Because if any variable is *null* it will definitly contains in other variable. The other two specs is just for non-null entries.

Comment: It doesn't get rid of the `case-sensitive` issue,does it ?

Comment: Now it does. I fixed example. It will ignore case, culture and correctly process null entries.

Comment: Personally I'd see `null` as unknown.  Does a string contain an unknown value?  That would be unknown and personally I'd go with it being false, not true.

Comment: @juharr Or even throw an argument null exception

Answer (score 0):

To check if substring is contained in main string, and to ignore case-sensitivity do this, its a boolean function that takes two string parameters:

```
public bool DoesStringExistInsideMainString(string mainString, string subString)
{
    return mainString.ToLower().Contains(subString.ToLower());

}
```