# Unable to protect the routes in Mvc5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

I'm trying to filter the routes based on the permissions assigned to user, here is my override in `BaseController` :

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        controllerName = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString().ToLower();
        actionName = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString().ToLower();
        hasParam = filterContext.ActionParameters.Where(d=>d.Value!=null).Count();
        if (!User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
        {

            if (controllerName == "campaign" && actionName == "index" && !IdentityHelper.HasPermission("CanAddCampaignApplication", userId))
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "dashboard", action = "Index" }));
            }

        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

The code is working fine on local machine, but the issue when I host the site is:

When I request the following Url, user redirected to the dashboard successfully

```
mysite.com/Campaign
```

But when I change from `Campaign` to `campaign` as follow:

```
mysite.com/campaign
```

The user got access to the requested URL instead of redirecting to the dashboard, I've searched a lot but I didn't get the issue yet, Please Help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make a case insensitive comparison using `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` (refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121957/how-can-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison) for example)

Comment: But I'm already converting the segments to lower case. Even it is still compulsory to make a CI comparison.

Comment: Can you 100% confirm that the authenticated user your testing is **not** part of the `Administrator` role and does **not** have the permission for `CanAddCampaignApplication`?

Comment: Yes I'm 100%  sure because the matter is  Case-sensitivity.

Comment: thanks @StephenMuecke..It works.