# Any.Equals to case insensitive

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement

I want to make this case insensitive:

```
 if (usernames.Any(newName.Equals))
```

i have earlier used stringcomparer and regex to make things case insensitive but here the problem is that the method don't allow more arguments. I'm thankful for any help! :)

Edit: Forgot to say that usernames is a string array and newName is a string(my inputfield) if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite predicate for `Any` a little bit

```cs
if (usernames.Any(n => newName.Equals(n, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
{
    //rest of code
}
```

Comment: Just interested, why the answer was downvoted

Comment: I keep refreshing the page Im more amazed by the number of  upvote. Imo it's a duplicate. And thats a lot of people standing in front of the roomba trying to salvage this question

Comment: @DragandDrop I guess that OP is asking how to use propery `StringComparison` with `Equals` within method group, rather then how to use it in `Any` method

Answer (score 0):

Use String.Equals instead.

```
String.Equals(x.Username, (string)drUser["Username"], 
                   StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13965429/1543596)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.Equals` which can handle `NULL` values:

```
if (usernames.Any(u => string.Equals(u, newName, 
    StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
{

}
```

[As msdn says about Equals(String, String):](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netframework-4.8)

> Determines whether two String objects have the same value.
>
> **Parameters a String**
>
> The first string to compare, **or null.**
>
> **Parameters b String**
>
> String The second string to compare, **or null.**